# Как создать в Android Studio переключатель из двух прилегающих кнопок?

Tags: android, switch

[image: Макет этого переключателя]

Соответственно, при нажатии на белую кнопку, цвета меняются местами.

Comment: В макете разместить две кнопки, с зеленым фоном и с белым, которые прилегают друг к другу. Обрабатывать у каждой нажатие. Если в начале нажали на бедую, меняем у обеих кнопок фон, если на зеленую то ничего. При следующем нажатии уже наоборот.

Comment: вот готовая [есть библиотека](https://github.com/mvpleung/SwitchButton), как раз то, что вам нужно/ Вот [еще одна](https://github.com/rcketscientist/ToggleButtons)

Comment: @iamtihonov видимо как то надо еще и состояние получать, какая из них выделена, а какая - нет. Это лучше надо виджет кастомный делать, чем просто две кнопки и логика в активити.

Comment: @pavlofff Ради маленького переключателя библиотеку использовать думаю не разумно, состояние можно просто булькой отслеживать. Свой виджет думаю будет хорошим вариантом.

Comment: @iamtihonov если вы посмотрите, то вся библиотека - один класс на пару десятков строк кода. В общем то она и есть готовый катомный виджет и ее можно еще упростить, если убрать возможность делить на произвольное количество кнопок, оставив только на две. Вторая посложнее, там 2 класса аналогичного первой объема.

Comment: @pavlofff не посмотрел исходники. Согласен.

Comment: @pavlofff, я попробовал первую библиотеку, она что-то не прижилась. Возникает эксепшн Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x10 при выполнении строки 94 в SwitchButton.java (mParentHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(1, 0);)
Причём компиляция примера проходит успешно. Я уже все res-файлы скопировал в проект, а всё равно не хочет работать